# Python os.walk looping folders in a pattern to rename

Tags: python, loops, os.walk

Hi I'm trying to learn the os.walk module

Thank you in advance

Aim: rename all folders in 'student folder'
To read 1, 2 ,3 ,4

Problem:
My code only renames the first folder to 1 successfully others remain the same.

```py
for root, sub, files in os.walk(my_dir):
    for x in sub:
        count = 0
        new_name = count + 1
        os.rename(f'{root}/{x}', f'{root}/{new_name}')
```

Comment: please include code in question not just a pic

Comment: Have you tried printing `count`?

Comment: But that wouldn't rename the new folders. I added the count because I understand this will help change the numbers 2,3,4 for each itteration

Comment: Please observe that count is set to 0 in every iteration of your loop and so new_name will always be 0 + 1 which explains why you see all folders being renamed to 1 (well, the others fail to be renamed because rename will fail if the target name is already taken).  See a code recommendation in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you never increase the count.  You might as well drop the `new_name` variable completely and go for something like this:

```
for root, sub, files in os.walk(my_dir):
    count = 0 
    for x in sub:
        count += 1
        os.rename(f'{root}/{x}', f'{root}/{count}')
```

Comment: Omg you are right! The new name variable is pointless, I should have added 'count' as you suggested. Lovely, will try it when I get back home

Comment: Worked beautifully  Mark.  Can I ask why does the *count =0 variable need to be outside the nestled for loop but inside the 1st floor loop?  I understand I'll get an error otherwise but I want to know the logic.

Comment: Great question.  The idea is to initialize `count` to 0 (that is, start counting again from 0) before we enter the `for x` loop.    If we initialized within the `for x` loop, count would be set to 0 every time.  You've already seen this problem in your initial attempt, the os.rename tried to change every file to `{root}/1` and only the first succeeded (since you can't rename to an existing file name.  HTH

Comment: Thank you for the explanation this will surely help me in my path .

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you're implementing a counter like this, `enumerate` is usually the more pythonic option:

```py
for root, sub, files in os.walk(my_dir):
    for count, x in enumerate(sub):
        os.rename(f'{root}/{x}', f'{root}/{count}')
```

Comment: Definitely a good use of enumerate.